# How to read DIO port?

Tags: c++, gpio

I am working on a project based on qt 4.8.5 and C++, the system is ubuntu 1404 and the motherboard in the pc was a DL631-c226 (information on DFI.COM ).

In the specification there is a DIO digital input output port 8 bits.

I read and I see every where on the web the simplest command is;

> echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/export

And after that a directory has been created but on my system it is not. Nothing happen even if I send the command using sudo root or root or admin

I get an error message "permission denied".

There is nothing in the BIOS regarding the DIO or GPIO configuration, in the kernel the GPIO is set to YES

I need help to read the value as changed on the pin of the DIO of my motherboard.

Comment: The specific command is "echo your_gpio_number > /sys/class/gpio/export" Without knowing which gpio you want to export the system cannot do what you need. What does a directory listing of /sys/class/gpio show you?

Comment: the sys/class/gpio directory contains only export and unexport with -w- --- --- rigth on it

Comment: In that case your kernel driver is not exposing your DIO through sysfs, or the driver is not loaded. You may need a specific driver for the DL631 in addition to general kernel GPIO support.

Comment: i have find the cdrom of the motherboard, but there is only windows driver on it, do you have any idea where i can find most popular driver for that kind of port ( digital input/ output ) , i read in the manual that i2c device has been mentionned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface to the DIO port is over i2c. Consulting their manual you can see an example of how to talk to it. I suggest you investigate i2c under Linux to understand how to handle it. At the very least you will need to install i2c tools and ensure your kernel has i2c support in it.

Their example: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/725217/Dfi-Dl631-C226.html?page=75#manual

Comment: i have just install the i2ctools, now it is time to exploit it